# Javascript - Reload page after form submit with target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, reload, target

I'm trying to achive the following:
On page A we have an access restricted Link to page B. The access restriction is handled on the server side in PHP.
When a user clicks on this link to page B we display a modal dialogue on page A (via javascript) with a form, having the link's href (B) as the action. (To give the user an immediate feedback. The fallback is to redirect him to a login form that redirects him to the site he wants to access.)
This system works quite well.

But now comes my question:
We have access restricted links that should be opened in a new window.
Now if I use target="_blank" on the form the user stays logged out on the page he came from (A), that is still open in the background.
Is there a way to reload the page (A, in the background) right after the form has been submitted to the new window (B)?

My first idea was to use window.location.reload(); in the submit handler on page A.
This didn't work in chrome and from what I understand could create a race condition.

Another idea would be to log the user in via an ajax call and open a new window through javascript. Is there a way to do this without having to deal with pop-up blockers?

---

I implemented the idea of lostsource (see below) with one slight addition.
As I need to reload only once, the timer of setInterval can be stopped if the cookie changed.

```
var ri=setInterval(function() {  
    if(oldCookie != document.cookie) {  
        // assuming a login happened, reload page  
        clearInterval(ri);  
        window.location.reload();  
    }  
},1000); // check every second
```

I still love the idea. stackoverflow is awsome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're storing PHP session information inside a cookie, you might be able to monitor your document.cookie for changes.

Before submitting the form store the value of the current cookie and monitor it for changes with a timer:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
     var oldCookie = document.cookie;

     var cookiePoll = setInterval(function() {
         if(oldCookie != document.cookie) {
             // stop polling
             clearInterval(cookiePoll);

             // assuming a login happened, reload page
             window.location.reload();
         }
     },1000); // check every second
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I love the concept.  
Just one slight addition:
If you don't stop the interval for such a fast interval it repeats even before the page could reload, making it hang effectively.
So I added a clear interval:
`var ri=setInterval(function() {
        if(oldCookie != document.cookie) {
          // assuming a login happened, reload page
          clearInterval(ri);
          window.location.reload();
        }
      },1000); // check every second`

Answer (score 0):

On the parent page, do you have any visual/functional changes because of the login? As in any new actions possible?
If not, then you dont have to do anything as you would be checking for login on every action from the parent page, you can check for permissions along with that.

If there are changes or additional functionalities, you can call a javascript function in the parent, say `reloadMe`, using `window.opener.reloadMe()`

Comment: Yes, sorry for making that not clear enough. As the modal dialogue can be opened from any page (from the navigation) the changes on the parent page (page A) can be quite substantial.
Does window.opener work from a window opened by a target="_blank" form?

Comment: I think it does. Do you face any problems?

Comment: Thank you very much!  
I took the suggestion of lostsource because it is a bit more flexible, as I don't have to manipulate the target page.
Your answer is still very valuable. Sorry I can't upvote it because I just created an account.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a simple `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 1000);
```

It is a bit hacky, but seems appropriate for your situation.